# Show message if there is an error in the form in angular 2

Tags: angular2-forms

I have the following form and I need that after the user clicks Save, an error message shows next to the radio group that is required (but no radio selected). I tried the following but it doesn't show the message at all.

```
<form #formList="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Save(formList)">
    <div *ngFor="let item of data">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      <input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected" required>Foo
      <input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected">Bar
      <div *ngIf="formList.controls.item?.id.required">
        The radio is required!
      </div>
    </div>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<form #formList="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Save(formList)">
    <div *ngFor="let item of data">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      <input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected" required>Foo
      <input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected">Bar
      <div *ngIf="!formList.form.valid">
        The radio is required!
      </div>
    </div>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```